For a vector $\alpha$ what can be said about the rank of $(I_n-\alpha \alpha ^t) $.
For a vector $\alpha$ what can be said about the rank of $(I_n-\alpha \alpha ^t) $.
My approach:
$r(I_n-\alpha \alpha ^t)\leq r(I_n) + r(\alpha \alpha ^t) \leq n+n =2n$.
But a square matrix of order $n$ can have at most $n$ independent columns. So $r(I_n-\alpha \alpha ^t)\leq n$.
Is it possible to make the bound more tight?

It's worth noting that the rank of $\alpha\alpha^\top$ is at most $1$, so your bound could be relaxed to the equally useless $n + 1$, instead of $2n$. Instead, consider what the eigenvalues of $\alpha\alpha^\top$ must be, and how they're related to the eigenvalues of $I_n - \alpha\alpha^\top$.

If $\def\a{\alpha}\a$ is a unit vector, then
$,{\rm Rank}(I_n-\a\a^T) \equiv (n-{\tt1});$
